# Rendering iframe into React

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I've got the following component:

```
export default class VideoArchiveContent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      videos: []
    }
  } 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.VideosTracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      Meteor.subscribe('videos');
      const videos = Videos.find().fetch();
      this.setState({ videos })
    });
  };
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.VideosTracker.stop();
  };
  renderVideos = () => {
    return this.state.videos.map((video) => {
      return <div key={video._id}>{video.embed}</div>
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderVideos()}
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

I'm expecting the iframe to render to the screen. What renders is the iframe string.

If I place the iframe in the return statement like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/270962511" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
)
```

The iframe renders as expected.

Is there a solution?

Comment: what is `video.embed` and where is the `iframe` in the first code block?

Comment: Have you tried using portals?  https://devdocs.io/react/portals

Comment: @Sagiv video.embed is the iframe=<iframe src=...></iframe>. The iframe is in a Mongo database. It's iterating over each iframe code.

Comment: You should provide better context. Displaying the output as well as errors can help debug the code. Firstly, there is no src for the iframe you are trying to display. Secondly, I found this useful for me https://video-react.js.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure where is the `iframe` comes from as i don't see it in your code as an `HTML` tag so i'm guessing it is coming from the server as a string. Probably inside `video.embed`.
If this is the case then you would need to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute to render this:

```
return <div key={video._id} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:video.embed}} />
```

Use it with caution, I advice to read about it in the [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) first.

Running example:

```js
const tweetersIframe = '<iframe src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html" />'
const App = () => (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: tweetersIframe}}>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This did fix the issue. I'm wondering if this is the only solution for rendering iframes, considering the danger.

Comment: I think a better option is to get the url from the server and render the `iframe` yourself instead of receiving the html as a string. There is no other way to render html tags as strings

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.